# Starting a Java-process in Go

Tags: java, go, classpath

I am trying to start a Java-process using  Go but am unable to get Java to recognise the classpath. The code looks somewhat like:

```
args := []string{
  "-Xmx64m",
  "-Dmy.property=value,
  "-cp",
  "lib/jar1.jar:lib/jar2.jar",
  "com.things.MyClass",
}
c := exec.Command(javaBinary, args...)
```

Unfortunately when executing this I get the dreaded `Error: Could not find or load main class` from the JVM. However if I take the output from `c.Args` and run it directly in a terminal it seems to work just fine, which to me indicates that I am somehow launching the process incorrectly.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Disregard this question please, the error was an extra space in the args array:

```
args := []string{
  "-Xmx64m",
  "-Dmy.property=value ", //<--trailing space
  ...
}
```

The extra space stops further parsing from continuing leading to a missing classpath.